# Compute the derivative of a distribution

Tags: complex-analysis

Hi i started complex analysis a few weeks back so im relatively new at this. We have arrived at the distributions and there was this exercise that i dont know how to continue it and was hoping for some help

The exercise goes like this:

Let $f(x) = |x|\mathbb{1}_{[−1,2]}(x)$ with x ∈ R. Compute the first derivative $(T^1_f)$

What i did was to "split" the f(x) into

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
 0,&x<-1\\
 -x, &-1 < x \leq 0\\
x, &0< x \leq 2\\
 0,&x> 2
\end{cases}$$

But im not sure on how to proceed!

Answer (score 1):

Write $f(x)$ in terms of shifted unit step functions $u_c(x)$ where $u_c(x)$ is $0$ if $x < c$ and $1$ if $x \ge c$. Then show that the distributional derivative of $u_c(x)$ is the delta function $\delta(x - c)$ by demonstrating that $\int_{\Bbb R} u_c'(x) \phi(x)\, dx = \phi(c)$ for all test functions $\phi$.